# How can I find and replace in an encoded markdown file?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a script that pulls a markdown file from github. I then decode the file find and replace parameters in that file with user given inputs.

```
tempdict = {'key_1': 'input_1', 'key 2','input_2'}
```

It worked great until I realized that it was missing some instances. I realized that the text was read in chunks of size 256 bytes, and if my 'key' was at the end of this chunk, then it would be on a different line of `rawtext` and my find and replace function would miss it. How can I avoid this error?

Code below:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foo/documents/master/bar.md'
rawtext = requests.get(fullurl)

rep = {}
for k,v in tempdict.items():
    rep[k.replace('_','\\_')]=v

decodedtext = []
for line in rawtext:
    decodedtext.append(line.decode("utf-8"))

editedtext = []
rep = dict((re.escape(k),v) for k,v in rep.items())

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(rep.keys()))
for line in decodedtext:
    line = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))],line)
    editedtext.append(line)


encodedtext =[]
for line in editedtext:
    encodedtext.append(str.encode(line))

markdownfile = open('edited.md','wb')
for i in encodedtext:
    markdownfile.write(i)
markdownfile.close()
```

Psuedo-Markdown file below.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pharetra, 
urna ullamcorper congue aliquet, leo nulla facilisis ipsum, tincidunt 
suscipit eros erat tempor orci. Sed porttitor convallis ligula, a pharetra 
nisl rhoncus sit key_1. Maecenas consequat sem nec urna mattis, non ornare 
risus fermentum. Nam consectetur volutpat felis sed blandit. Etiam eu 
sollicitudin diam, eu euismod diam. Fusce diam libero, sagittis varius elit 
nec, ultricies key_2 est. Sed nibh purus, tincidunt eu fringilla ut, 
ultrices et orci.
```

Anytime I tried to use `rawtext.text` or `rawtext.iter_items()` it wouldn't keep the markdown format. Also, I replace the items in `tempdict` to `rep` because the `rawtext` adds `\\` before every underscore.

Comment: "Anytime I tried to use `rawtext.text` or `rawtext.iter_items()` it wouldn't keep the markdown format." — Cannot reproduce; using `rawtext.text` should be the correct solution to your problem.

Comment: You're right, not sure what I was doing wrong, but `rawtext.text` works. If you add it I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are checking each section of a list for a match, which means that if a match is partially in 2 list entries then it will not be matched. Instead of creating a list, create 1 string, split it by new lines (assuming you are not trying to match any new lines) and perform your check against the new list.

```
decodedtext = ""
for line in rawtext:
    decodedtext += line.decode("utf-8")
...
for line in decodedtext.split("\n"):
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this works, but I have gone with the `rawtext.text` solution as it is a bit simpler.